# create large objects in oracle via sqlplus

Tags: oracle, continuous-integration, oracle11g, sqlplus, ddl

I have a view whose DDL definition is many thousands of lines long. Part of our CI process is to drop and recreate views from DDL using SQLPlus called from a command line script.

This works for hundreds of views in the database but the very large view is never created in the target schema. I always manually paste the view creation script into Toad and run it manually after the automated process has completed. This is a drag.

There is no meaningful error message from SQLPlus when the large-view portion of the DDL script is run but I suspect that it fails because of it's size.

Is there a "set" command that I can include at the top of my DDL to tell SQLPlus that it's ok to create large views or am I forever doomed to include a stoopid manual step in the otherwise automatic CI process?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, use the most recent version of SQLPlus. Its been a long time since I had a piece of code that was too large to be executed through SQLPlus. You can use the InstantClient

I'd also look at re-factoring the view. Look at the [WITH](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#sthref9758) clause as that is relatively new and, if the view has evolved over a long period, there's a good chance it can be amended to make use of this

Answer (score 0):

Is there an empty line in the view SQL, or does any line have more than 2499 characters?  Either one of these may cause SQL*Plus to behave unexpectedly but not actually fail.

If there is an empty line, Oracle will ignore everything before it and try to run everything after it.  (This only applies to SQL, not PL/SQL.)  For example, if you have an empty line right after the `create view` line, the query will run:

```
SQL> create or replace view newline_in_the_middle as
  2
SQL> select * from dual;

D
-
X
```

A line with >2499 characters will be ignored but Oracle will still try to process the statement without it.  This can cause problems but may still result in a valid statement:

```
SQL> create or replace view long_line as
  2  select '...[enter 2500 characters]...' asdf from dual union all
SP2-0027: Input is too long (> 2499 characters) - line ignored
  2  select '1' asdf from dual;

View created.
```

You may have to check the script output very carefully to find these issues.